# Developing App Widget in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appwidget

When developing App Widget with Android Studio, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error running app: Default activity not found
```

However, this is an App Widget, not an application, and even more, it used to work in the past.
How can I cause Android Studio to run the App Widget without modifying the manifest file?

Comment: I do not know any way to "run" an app widget, or even what that would mean or look like. You can install the APK, then work with the app widget on your device or emulator as normal. You can change your run configuration to launch "Nothing", and that will simply install the APK without trying to start any component.

Comment: Tanks a lot. Especially for the change in run configuration (without this the apk was not created in app/build/outputs/apk/).

Answer (score 7):

To run (actually install) `App Widget` using `Android Studio`, go to: `Run -> Edit Configurations -> General tab` in `Launch Options / Launch` and choose `Nothing`